# diode equivalent circuit model AC analysis

Tags: capacitor, diodes, ac, high-frequency, modeling

[image: Forward Biased AC Diode Model]

I've understood the small-signal analysis for the diode, like how is the value for rd derived. But here are somethings i don't understand:

1. How is capacitance of the diode dependent on the frequency of source?
2. Why is capacitor in parallel with the resistor? Why not is series?
3. How is all this different for reverse biased? With operating in high and low frequency?

Comment: It's unclear why a "theoretical" model would have two capacitors in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all answers to your 3 questions are the same:

That's up to the model you're studying here, not universally fixed.

We can't tell you how the capacitance depends on the frequency in your model, because we don't know much about that model. To be exact, we only know that this is some model you've found, it applies to a forward-biased diode with a small AC signal atop of the DC bias, and that's it.

I'd agree, for example, that it'd make sense to see the junction capacitance in series with a resistance; but not the differential resistance \$r_d\$; so, you'd need to *add* one resistor. Bam! We've changed the model. It's now a different model than the one you're studying. Is that good? Maybe, our new model is more exact in some respect. Maybe the added complexity makes it impossible to calculate or explain something in the literature you're readin.

So: *Models model a physical device, just well enough for a specific purpose.* The assumptions made and descriptions of the elements of the model come with the model. Nobody else but the text you're reading can thus answer the questions you're sking here.

Comment: Diodes have inductance too, a few nano henries. It's just a model. It's $$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{your}}}$$ model (as Marcus implies).

Answer (score 1):

Marcus has given a very general answer, which is completely correct.

But I think we an actually give some useful answers for the specific model you've presented.

> How is capacitance of the diode dependent on the frequency of source?

Ideally, it shouldn't. Practically, the model might fail at very high frequencies due to the inductance that Andy mentioned in comments to Marcus' answer.

> Why is capacitor in parallel with the resistor? Why not is series?

Because the diode doesn't block signals at very low frequencies. Even at 1 Hz or 0.001 Hz, a small change in the voltage across the diode will cause a change in the current through it (or vice versa). That's a good indicator that there shouldn't be any series capacitor in the model of the diode.

> How is all this different for reverse biased?

The value of \$r_d\$ will increase (dramatically) and \$C_j\$ (the junction capacitance, resulting from the change in the depth of the depletion region as the voltage changes) will decrease. \$C_D\$ (the diffusion capacitance, caused by the carriers involved in carrying the current) will effectively disappear in the reverse bias case.

> With operating in high and low frequency?

I think this has already been answered.